# Detect html element property changes dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two buttons - A and B. If A becomes disabled/enabled I want B to always be the same.

Is there a simple way to do this in JavaScript?

Let's assume there's no click event etc. I just want to monitor the state of A and B change accordingly.

Comment: _If A becomes disabled/enabled_ how it will change?

Comment: Sure, you just write the code.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki via a validation library - but I'm more interested in how you'd do this generally.

Comment: You've to fire a function that check if the button A is `enabled/disabled` and change B depending to the result just after changing the status. else you've to use `DOM Mutation Events.` to listen to a DOM attribute change.

Answer (score 1):

```js
// WITH CLICK ----------------------------------------------------
/*
$("#dissablebtnA").on("click", function() {
  $("#btnA").attr("disabled", "disabled");
  if ($("#btnA").attr("disabled") == "disabled") {
    console.log("dissabled button B because button A is disabled");
    $("#btnB").attr("disabled", "disabled");
  }

});
*/

// WITHOUT CLICK ----------------------------------------------------
/*
If you just want to monitor it without clicking you could do like this 
*/

// check every 5 seconds to see if it is dissabled and set b to dissabled accordingly
window.setInterval(function(){
  
 if ($("#btnA").attr("disabled") == "disabled") {
    console.log("dissabled button B because button A is disabled");
    $("#btnB").attr("disabled", "disabled");
   
  }
}, 5000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnA">button A</button>
<button id="btnB">button B</button>
<br>
<br>
<button id="dissablebtnA">DISABLE BUTTON A</button>
```